# Call template odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I create template in module `labs`.

```
 <template id="worbook_employee_miss_message">
                                    <t t-if="time_research">
                                        <div>
                                            <span style="color: red">test</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </t>
                                </template>
```

I call it in formview

```
<t t-call="labs.worbook_employee_miss_message">
                                <t t-set="time_research" t-value="time_research"/>

                            </t>
```

But there is no block div on form. `time_research` field is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it's ok. Be sure to call the template inside a

```
<div class="page">

</div>
```